# How to use fofkJoin to get multiple results then using the results?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs5

I have multiple http request in angular 5 application.

```
const response1 = this.http.get('url1').subscribe(data => {
    this.list1 = data;
});

const response2 = this.http.get('url2').subscribe(data => {
    this.list2 = data;
});

const response3 = this.http.get('url3').subscribe(data => {
    this.list3 = data;
});

const response4 = this.http.get('url4').subscribe(data => {
    this.list4 = data;
});
```

So I can get `this.list1`, `this.list2`, `this.list3` and `this.list4`. Then I want to use these data to render the UI. I used the sequential call and took some time. Now I want to use forkJoin.

My code likes.

```
const response1 = this.http.get('url1').subscribe(data => {
    this.list1 = data;
});

const response2 = this.http.get('url2').subscribe(data => {
    this.list2 = data;
});

const response3 = this.http.get('url3').subscribe(data => {
    this.list3 = data;
});

const response4 = this.http.get('url4').subscribe(data => {
    this.list4 = data;
});

return Observable.forkJoin([response1, response2, response3, response4]).then(this.loadUiFromAllList());
```

I am not sure how to use it correctly? How can I get the results from forkJoin then doing something? This is for `rxjs 5.5.6.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forkJoin takes Observables, not subscriptions which are returned by subscribe method. So you need to a little refactor your code.

Also there is no need to import Observable. You could import forkJoin directly.

Here is nice source of knowledge and examples: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

```js
import {forkJoin} from "rxjs/observable/forkJoin";
```

```js
const source1 = this.http.get('url1');

const source2 = this.http.get('url2');

const source3 = this.http.get('url3');

const source4 = this.http.get('url4');

return forkJoin([source1, source2, source3, source4])
  .subscribe(([response1, response2, response3, response4]) => {
    // here you can assign responses to properties: 
    // this.list1 = response1...
    this.loadUiFromAllList()
  },
  (error) => {
    // here you can handle error
  });
```

Comment: forkjoin is imported from rxjs

Comment: @bryan60, Hello ask about rxjs 5.5.6

Comment: Does your code work in `rxjs 5.5.6` and can you catch the exception?

Comment: This should work in version 5.5.6 and you can catch error by passing second callback to subscribe method

Comment: If you could add the exception part it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, you could also send the input observables as an object instead of an array. It makes it easier to keep track of the response when there are too many responses in the subscription.

For eg. you could something like following

Service

```js
getData() {
  return forkJoin(
    {
      url1: this.http.get('url1').pipe(catchError(e => of('url1 error'))),
      url2: this.http.get('url2').pipe(catchError(e => of('url2 error'))),
      url3: this.http.get('url3').pipe(catchError(e => of('url3 error'))),
      url4: this.http.get('url4').pipe(catchError(e => of('url4 error'))),
    }
  )
```

You could then refer to the results using their keys in the subscription

Controller

```js
this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log(result.url1);
    console.log(result.url2);
    console.log(result.url3);
    console.log(result.url4);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost doing it right.
forkJoin returns an observable and not a promise.
Therefor this should look something like this:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
...
sub: Subscription;
...
this.sub = forkJoin(
    [response1, response2, response3, response4]
).subscribe(([res1, res2, res3, res4]: [type1, type2, type3, type4]) => {
    // logic
});
```

Please remember that each subscribe returns a subscription object which should be removed on destroy.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: It is not an answer. Just a comment.

Comment: I explained every step of the way. why this is not an answer? I hope you'll find it useful.

Comment: You need to unsubcribe only when observable is not completed. In case of Http requests observable is completed after revceiving response from server

Answer (score 0):

forkJoin "join" Observables

So, in general you has a service

```
getData()
{
  return forkJoin([this.http.get('url1'),
                   this.http.get('url2'),
                   this.http.get('url3'),
                   this.http.get('url4')])
}
```

And in a component you subscribe to getData

```
this.dataService.subscribe(([list1, list2, list3, list4])=>{
   this.list1=list1
   this.list2=list2
   this.list3=list3
   this.list4=list4
   ..do here what do you want..
})
```

Well, in rxjs 5.5.6 forkJoin is

```
Observable.forkJoin([...])
```

Yes, the Observables (and Angular is full plenty of Observables) are "functions" that you subscribe to it. Is INTO the "subscribe" function where you "received the data and where you can call to another functions

Comment: I am little confused by your code. How `this.dataService.subscribe` links to `forkJoin`?

Comment: @Hello, this is suggestion that you should split your logic between service (injectable) and component. **dataService** service should be injected into components constructor, but here is mistake. This should be: "this.dataService.getData().subscribe(..."